# java copy-of xsl transformation removes namespace prefix

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I made a minimal example to reproduce the problem. This is the transformation (mini.xsl):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <foo>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </foo>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and this is the input (mini.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bar xmlns:x="baz">
    <x:baz/>
</bar>
```

When I apply the transformation with

```
xsltproc mini.xsl mini.xml
```

the result looks as expected:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<foo>
  <bar xmlns:x="baz">
    <x:baz/>
  </bar>
</foo>
```

However, when I run the transformation with the following Java program,

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.Result;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.Templates;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactoryConfigurationError;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class Program
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Source transform = new StreamSource(new FileInputStream(args[0]));

            Templates templates = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTemplates(transform);

            Document input = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(new FileInputStream(args[1]));

            Result result = new StreamResult(System.out);           

            templates.newTransformer().transform(new DOMSource(input), result);
        }
        catch (TransformerFactoryConfigurationError | ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException | TransformerException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

the result looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo>
  <bar xmlns:x="baz">
    <baz/>
  </bar>
</foo>
```

(notice that the x: prefix in front of baz is missing.)

Why is that?

And what can I do about it (to preserve the namespace prefix)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For what I can only assume are historical reasons, `DocumentBuilderFactory` is *non-namespace-aware* by default.  You need to explicitly switch on namespaces before you do `newDocumentBuilder()`.

It would also be better to use the `parse` method that takes a `File` directly rather than creating your own `FileInputStream` (which your code is not closing once the parse is finished), and likewise with the `StreamSource` from which the `Transformer` is built.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
Document input = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new File(args[1]));
```

Comment: Better still, pass a StreamSource to the transform() method rather than a DOM. The DOM and XSLT don't actually mix that well, and most XSLT processors will do a much better job if you allow them to build the tree themselves.